# hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient: MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect error triggering other errors on hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql

From time to time, when developers run hive queries, they get the following error (first log entry below).

When I look through the hive longs on the node, I see that Metastoreclient lost connection immediately prior (2nd log entry below).

Problem seems to go away on its own.

Any idea what might be the root cause of this?

Thanks!

```
hadoop-cmf-hive-HIVESERVER2-qn7bi02hdn001.compliant.disney.private.log.out.3:2016-04-27 07:17:20,092 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

[root@qn7bi02hdn001 rashm010]# grep lost *3
```

2016-04-27 07:16:54,449 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient: MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect.
2016-04-27 07:17:20,114 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient: MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect.
[root@qn7bi02hdn001 rashm010]#

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information it could be anything, but some things that you will want to check:

- Network
- Firewall

If the infra is eliminated as cause it gets more tricky, but it could perhaps be security tokens expiring or a resource shortage resulting in timeouts.

If possible it is recommended to reach out to the support desk of your platform provider for detailed troubleshooting.